# How can I properly copy nested dictionary objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm working on a project with **Python 2.7** where I have a "complex" dictionary structure, and I was trying to do something like this:

```
generic_dict = {
     'user': {'created': {}, 'modified': {}, 'errors': {}},
     'usermon': {'created': {}, 'modified': {}, 'ignored': {}, 'errors': {}}


log_data = {
    'esp': generic_dict,
    'por': generic_dict,
    'sui': generic_dict,
    'ben': generic_dict,
    'mex': generic_dict,
    'arg': generic_dict,
}
```

I was trying to use the generic dict to avoid repeating code but I have a problem if I do like this, when I modify any of the country dicts (esp, ben, por) all are modifying at the same time.

Let's assume the dictionary is empty and I do this

```
log_data['esp']['user']['created']['today'] = 'asdasdasda'
```

all the other dicts now have the same value like generic_dict is the same all of them.

```
print log_data['ben']['user']['created']
Output: {'today': 'asdasdasda'}
print log_data['ben']['user']['created']
Output: {'today': 'asdasdasda'}
```

I understand what's happening but I don't know how to avoid that

- Which is the best way copy nested dictionary objects ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to create a new copy of the `generic_dict` object, like this

```
from copy import deepcopy

log_data = {
    'esp': deepcopy(generic_dict),
    'por': deepcopy(generic_dict),
    'sui': deepcopy(generic_dict),
    'ben': deepcopy(generic_dict),
    'mex': deepcopy(generic_dict),
    'arg': deepcopy(generic_dict),
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can have a constructor function, like this

```
def generic_dict():
    return {'user': {'created': {}, 'modified': {}, 'errors': {}},
            'usermon': {'created': {}, 'modified':{}, 'ignored': {}, 'errors': {}}}
```

And then call it to create a new dictionary object every time, like this

```
log_data = {
    'esp': generic_dict(),
    'por': generic_dict(),
    'sui': generic_dict(),
    'ben': generic_dict(),
    'mex': generic_dict(),
    'arg': generic_dict(),
}
```