# Why is the attribute of dict immutable object, and the list in it is mutable object

Tags: python

I was watching explore python. It had an example:

```
    >>> d1 = {'name': 'ethan', 'books': ['book1', 'book2', 'book3']}
    >>> d2 = d1.copy()
    >>> d2['name'] = 'peter'         
    >>> d2
    {'books': ['book1', 'book2', 'book3'], 'name': 'peter'}
    >>> d1
    {'books': ['book1', 'book2', 'book3'], 'name': 'Ethan'}
```

Is a dict not a value-key object? Why it said the value of name is an immutable object, so the properties of d1 will not change.

Comment: Dictionaries *aren't* immutable. That code explicitly creates a separate (albeit *shallow*) copy.

Comment: The value of name is a string, which is immutable. But it is not mutated anywhere here. The *dictionary* is mutable and you can tell it to associate a different value to a given key.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How can I properly copy nested dictionary objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188560/how-can-i-properly-copy-nested-dictionary-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary `copy` method explicitly creates a copy. This has nothing to do with mutability. Try

```
d2=d1
```

to see what you expect. Besides, what it means for an object to be mutable is you **cannot change it**. Try to change a tuple for example:

```
x=(1,2,3)
x[0]=4
```

Note - this has nothing to do with other variables. In fact, try:

```
(1,2,3)[0]=4
```

**Small edit**

The copy of `d1` is shallow, meaning the list of `books` has only it's reference copied. Thus, changing **the list**, will be seen by all things pointing to it - both dicts. Note, the list changed, not the dicts.

Comment: But what if  I  remove books. D1 is changed?

Comment: >>> d2['books'].remove('book2')  
        >>> d2
        {'books': ['book1', 'book3'], 'name': 'peter'}
        >>> d1
        {'books': ['book1', 'book3'], 'name': 'ethan'}

Comment: @cclsr The reason you you *can remove* is that a dictionary is mutable (can be changed). Again, when you run `d1.copy()` you are creating a `new, totally different` dictionary. Changes in one of them have nothing to do with the other. *BUT*, the list inside was not copied, it's just referenced by both! So here, you will change the `list`, which happens to be pointed to by both dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Because, to make the lookup faster, python calculates a *hash value* for each key of the dictionary. If the key object was changed from some other class, that doesn't know it is used as key in a dictionary, the dictionary would not be notified, and would look for it in the wrong place in subsequent lookups.